# Core data query

Tags: ios, core-data

> V <-->> O <<--> P

I am trying to write the right predicate so that I can get all `V` entities that have at least one or more `O` entities that match a certain `P` entity.

I've tried something like this:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(O, $b, ANY $bs.P == %@).@count > 0", P];
```

Not working. Obviously I am not thinking about this correctly so far. Any idea how I can get this query done properly?

Comment: You should see some useful stuff in the question and answers there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Still not sure how to write the predicate. I'll keep reading that question and answers to it you suggested in the meantime to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the relationship in V to O is called `os` and the relationship from O to P is called `p`.
The syntax for the subquery would be as follows:

```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"SUBQUERY(os, $o, $o.p == %@).@count != 0", pToMatch];
```

Comment: Right on. Thanks. Now I realize how easy this was, I'm still trying to get core data queries down. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Unfortunately, it's all very badly documented.